# Guidance on the use of pins of LM1117

Tags: voltage-regulator, layout, pins

I plan on using [this 3.3v regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&DCM=yes&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mouser.co.uk%2F)

It has 4 pins on the SOT-223 package

I plan on doing the following ( but want to check )

- Pin 1 - Gnd
- Pin 2 - Vout - 3.3v -- Tied to pin 4 feeding my circuit
- Pin 3 - Vin - 5v Supply
- Pin 4 - Vout - 3.3v -- Tied to pin 2 feeding my circuit

Does this look correct?

The reason I act is that pin 4 is a bit 'odd'. This question has set me straight : [LDO - SOT223 - What's the Fourth pin for?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/143511/ldo-sot223-whats-the-fourth-pin-for)

Basically its a tab for heatsinking, but it is typically connected to Pin 2.

Can I therefore safely just have a pad for the Tab(pin 4) with nothing connected to it? And use pin 2 for the vOUT alone?

Comment: Use an ohmmeter and check for continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often, pin 2 is not brought out to a pin you can solder to the board. Thus pin 4 is used.
The datasheet covers both options. See the TO-252 or DPAK. I use those when higher current is involved to increase the cooling area available. There pin 2 is still connected to the tab, but does not go down to the board for soldering.

Answer (score 4):

It is literally on page 3 of the datasheet, which you linked in the question.

[image]

Where exactly is the confusion? It states very clearly that Adj/GND in the SOT-223 is pin 1. Vin pin 3, and Vout is pins 2 and 4.

There should be no need to double check if you read this table. Remember the input and output capacitors.

Comment: I want to make sure my understand is right, and that i can join together pins 2 & 4?

Comment: See my updated question above

Comment: The datasheet and this answer are very clear. I wonder who downvoted this answer. +1 to compensate. Moreover at addresses the missing capacitors in OP's textual schematic.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Your updated question and I believe this answer still gives you the same answer. I don't think it was necessary to downvote this answer. If you're still confused on how to configure the pins, I recommend looking at some application notes for the datasheet. Just tie them together on the schematics. It's not like it will affect the way your system performs.

Comment: Hmm could the 2 downvoters explain why they thought this answer is wrong? From what I can see, it is very clearly correct. Even with the updated question, the answer still stands.